# How do i remove ubuntu dual boot from win 10?

Tags: 18.04

Recently I have installed ubuntu onto a win 10 machine so that it dual boots. I am finished with ubuntu and want to remove it  from win 10 safely. However I do not want to reinstall windows like some tutorials do and I don't have any disks to do so. **Is there anyway to remove Ubuntu and GRUB without Windows 10 disks?**

p.S i am running 18.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: You should always have a repair/recovery flash drive for Windows. And a full backup as hard drives do break.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is the usefull guide for you. I used a similar procedure to do the same thing you asked for.

[How to Remove Linux (Ubuntu) From Dual Boot in Windows 10](https://www.easytechstutorials.com/how-to-remove-linux-ubuntu-from-dual-boot-in-windows-10/)

NOTE: you can extend your Windows partition for recover space only if two partition are consecutive.